# Do scalars matter in big-O notation?

Tags: math, big-o

Are scalars included in big-O notation, or is O(2n) actually the same as O(n) because scalars are not taken into account?  If so, why is this?

Comment: For wall-clock time: yes/maybe. For academic purposes: no/usually not. Remember that *any* extra constant overhead will [eventually] be dominated ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Big-O notation ignores constant factors (scalars) because of its definition:

> f(n) = O(g(n)) iff there is a natural number n<sub>0</sub> and real number c such that for any natural number n > n<sub>0</sub>, |f(n)| ≤ |cg(n)|

So now suppose that f(n) = O(k × g(n)).  This means that there is some natural number n<sub>0</sub> and real number c such that for any n > n<sub>0</sub>, we have that |f(n)| ≤ |c × k × g(n)|.

We'll use this to show that f(n) = O(g(n)).  To do this, choose n<sub>0</sub> as your natural number and c × k as your real number.  Then for any n > n<sub>0</sub>, we have that |f(n)| ≤ |(c × k) × g(n)|, so f(n) = O(g(n)).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Keep in mind that the `=` stands for "in" or "is in", not for equality. `O(⋅)` is a set of functions.